# Mailchimp API adding tags to new and existing members

Tags: json, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to do a simple JSON call to add a tag to a new or existing subscriber.

It adds the subscriber's first name, last name, and email address, but not the tag. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is what I have:

```
public function apiUrl() {
        $apiKey = $this->Key;
        $listId = $this->ListID;
        $memberId = $memberId = md5(strtolower($this->Email));

        $getapi = substr($this->escape($apiKey), strpos($this->escape($apiKey), '-') + 1);
        return 'https://' . $this->escape($getapi) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $this->escape($listId) . '/members/' . $this->escape($memberId);
    }

    public function jsonData() {
        return json_encode(array(
            'email_address' => $this->escape($this->Email),
            'status' => $this->escape($this->Status),

            'tags' => ['name' => 'Calendar Users', 'status' => 'active'],

            'merge_fields' => array(
                'FNAME' => $this->escape($this->FName),
                'LNAME' => $this->escape($this->LName)
            )
        ));
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "everything works except the TAG"? What did you expect to happen with the "TAG" and what happened instead?

Comment: To add a TAG to that subscriber. It adds the subscriber fname, lname and email but not the TAG

Comment: Where did you expect the tag to appear? What are you looking at to determine that the tag was not added?

Comment: Inside of mailchimp! You can tag certain subscribers as they come in. https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/lists/list-members/list-member-tags/

Comment: According to that page, you are supposed to do a POST request to `/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}/tags`. I don't see where this code does that.

Comment: `return 'https://' . $this->escape($getapi) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $this->escape($listId) . '/members/' . $this->escape($memberId);`

Comment: ...`/tags` ...?

Comment: I see - yeah, your are right. Let me try that..

Answer (score 3):

I have found one more way to add tag in member. I think is is more helpful to create or add tag in member/contact while you create member/contact.

**So, you can create or add tag using following request -**

```
POST - https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members/{member_id}/tags
```

You need to pass the tag data/info in body or with request. **See below -**

```
{
    "tags": [
                {
                    "name" : "Tag_Name_1",
                    "status" : "active"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Tag_Name_2",
                    "status" : "active"
                }
            ]
  }
```

So, through the above process you can add give tag into given member or member_id. Please see below image of post request to create or add tag, it will help.

[Postman request sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGcOm.jpg)

**NOTE-** If give tag (tag name) is exist or available under given list_id/audience, it will used tag_id and if not it will create tag and add it's id (segment_id).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Mailchimp API providing to add tags to an existing members or contacts. So you can add tag definitely. It will be help to add new tag.

**One more thing you can add tag after creating member or contact.** So below post request help you to create or add tag. Here you can see in image when i sent post request, I got the response code **200 OK**. So first you need to prepare the post request with required parameter (list_id,segment_id). You only need to pass the "email_address" in body part.

**So you need to create tag first because we will need tag or segment id.** To create a new tag, make the following request.

```
POST- https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/segments
```

**and in body you can write like -**

```
{
    "name":"Tag_Name",
    "static_segment":[]
}
```

So after successfully creating tag you got segment id and using this id you can add it (tag) in any contact or member.

**Sample request for adding tag like -**

```
POST- `https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/segments/{segments_id}/members`
```

**and in body you can write like -**

```
{
    "email_address": "sample@email.com"
}
```

So, go ahead and do this. I attached one image for your reference, Please look. Good luck.

[Postman request sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma5U4.jpg)

Comment: Yes, this works in Postman and in a Repl I created, but not in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Below how to delete the tags already assigned and add just the tag needed it.

```
{
"tags": [
            {
                "name" : "status-user",
                "status" : "inactive"
            },                
            {
                "name" : "Unsubscribed_over_email",
                "status" : "inactive"
            }
            ,                
            {
                "name" : "status-user",
                "status" : "active"
            }
        ]
```

}